# Optional string in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to catch if the url is a blog page or not. A *blog page* can be:

- `/blog`
- `/blog/page/1`
- `/blog/page/143`

So, `page/pageNumber` is optional. How can I create a regular expression that being tested returns `true` if the url is a blog page?

I created the regex for urls containing `/page/` string and it seems to work fine:

```
/\/blog\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*)/
```

Example:

```
> /\/blog\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*)/.test("/blog/page/1")
true
> /\/blog\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*)/.test("/blog/page/0")
false
> /\/blog\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*)/.test("/blog/page/30")
true
```

But how can I set `/page/number` to be optional?

I tried:

```
/\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?/
```

This returns `true` for incorrect urls:

```
> /\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?/.test("/blog/p")
true
```

Comment: what's wrong with /^\/blog/i if you're using test() ?

Comment: @dandavis `/blog/1-my-interesting-post` is not the same with `/blog/page/1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an end marker (`$`) so that it stops checking.

```
> /\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?$/.test("/blog/p")
false
> /\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?$/.test("/blog/page/1")
true
> /\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?$/.test("/blog/page/0")
false
> /\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?$/.test("/blog/page/30")
true
> /\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?$/.test("/blog")
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add markers for the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string. In it's current form, your check will also return true if it only matches part of the string.

```
/^\/blog(\/page\/[1-9]([0-9]*))?$/
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/sO9sU1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to make `/page/num` optional:

```
/^\/blog(\/page\/\d+)?\/?$/
```

Comment: Yes it won't and that is not in the requirements either.

Comment: It will still match `/blog/p` and `/blog/page`. Since the Javascript `test()` method is satisfied with a partial match.

Comment: Yes true, have added anchors now to avoid that situation.

Comment: @anubhava Also, `/blog/page/0` shouldn't be matched. Anyways, thank you, all!

Answer (score 0):

You could use non capturing groups for this,

```
^\/blog(?:\/page(?:\/[1-9]\d*)?)?$
```

Comment: why would capturing matter when using /./.test() ?

Comment: @dandavis it won't capture anything.

Comment: @AvinashRaj This will catch `/blog/page/0` that is incorrect.